How many constant symbols can a set of intuitionistic formulas have for completeness to hold?
Fitting's proves a version of the completeness theorem for intuitionistic FOL in his Intuitionistic Logic Model Theory and Forcing:

Let $U$ be any set of formulas without parameters (i.e. constant symbols). Then $U \vdash X$ (in the intuitionistic sense) iff in any model $\mathcal{G}$, for any $\Gamma \in \mathcal{G}$, if $\Gamma \vDash U$, $\Gamma \vDash X$.

He later elaborates:

This may be extended to sets $S$ with some parameters. To be precise, to any set $S$ which leaves unused a countable collection of parameters.

First of all, let me clarify that Fitting uses the unfortunately common approach of only defining a first-order language with a countable set of parameters. So it is unclear to me how we could generalize this how languages are usually defined, so with a possibly uncountable set of parameters. If I had a language with $\kappa$ parameters, would this theorem now hold if a countable number were left out or if $\kappa$ many were left out?
I'm also looking for a proof of this fact (it's not as easily googlable as it may seem) and I wonder why we even need this condition. After all, this is not required in the classical case.
Editing to say that I've received a good answer here. Unfortunately can't delete because of the bounty.
